# add an lstm after an cnn

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

i have two cnn and i want to concatenate them and feed them to an lstm or bilstm
and this is the code

```py
input_text_ = Input(shape = (MAX_UTTERANCE_LENGTH,), dtype = 'int32') #MAX_UTTERANCE_LENGTH = 20
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(input_text_)
output_text_ = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
output_text_ = MaxPooling1D(2)(output_text_)
output_text_ = Conv1D(100, 5, activation='relu')(output_text_)
output_text_ = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(output_text_)
model_text = Model(inputs = input_text_, outputs = output_text_)

input_audio_ = Input(shape = (10, 4))
output_audio_ = Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu')(input_audio_)
output_audio_ = MaxPooling1D(2)(output_audio_)
output_audio_ = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(output_audio_)
output_audio_ = MaxPooling1D(2)(output_audio_)
output_audio_ = Reshape((32,))(output_audio_)
model_audio = Model(inputs = input_audio_, outputs = output_audio_)

concatenate = Concatenate()([output_audio_, output_text_])
concatenate = Bidirectional(LSTM(500, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.8))(concatenate)
```

the problem is the lstm give me this error of dimn

Input 0 of layer "bidirectional" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 132)

which one of this layers need to rechape dimn
any help And I am thankful

Comment: Check: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7403